# Validation procedure on validation set - NOT k-fold cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, cross-validation, supervised-learning

I'm new to python and machine learning and I'm having difficulty understanding validation step also would like to have a suggestion on what to do when I don't want to use k-folds cross-validation, but rather just use validation set. I've been reading around and can't seem to properly grasp the k-fold cross-validation:

1. Do I split INITIAL data into k folds, then train on k-1 and test on the 1 left, keep rotating aftewards - so each fold is used for testing and such.
2. Or do I split INITIAL data into Train and TEST data - then split Train data into k folds and do the cross-validation, then finally test the accuracy on unseen TEST data?
3. How the best parameters are chosen during k-folds cross-validation?
   Does cross_val_score after returning list of scores, apply the best parameters during validation step where the accuracy was the best? (Code below)

```
model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=5)
```

Or this step should be done manually (by me)? By using gridsearchcv and such ?

4. In my case I have an INITIAL data-set of 400.000 samples (rows lets say) and around 70 features (columns) Executing k-folds cross-validation on my data-set takes ages (Also from what I understand it's mainly used for smaller data-sets), instead I would like to have 3 sets of data: Training (90%) Validation (5%) and Testing (5%) - operate validation on that 5% and tune my model parameters during that step, then finally check accuracy on testing set. How one does go about it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have both training(labelled one) & test(unlabelled) data, then cross validation uses this training data itself, at every fold your data gets splitted into different train & test data, more like the second point you wrote.

No after cross validation hyperparameters will not be tuned, you will have to do it manually or by using grid or random search.

Since you mentioned cross-validation is taking too much time & you are thinking of using a validation dataset for hyperparamter tuning, I will suggest you to skip this whole part & throw your data to  Gradient Boosted Trees, your cross-validation part will be automatically solved and then later on tune parameters and check accuracy.

Even better suggestion throw your data to TPOT. It's a Python Automated Machine Learning library that optimizes machine learning pipelines using genetic programming. On running some good number of iterations, The output will be best optimized code with hyperparameters tuned, mostly an ensemble method, with the best accuracy you can get. It also mentions how other algos performed. It may take a long time to finish even longer than a Neural Net but sometimes worth it.